# MongoDB: Summing the number of times a value == "Some String" in an object within an array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB document that looks something like this:

```
{
  "_id": 000000000001,
  "sample": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "12345678910"
      },
      "Phone": 5555555555,
      "LastName": "Musk",
      "FirstName": "Elon",
      "responses": {
        "question1": "hello",
        "question2": "world"
      }
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "12345678911"
      },
      "Phone": "1111111111",
      "LastName": "Jobs",
      "FirstName": "Steve",
      "responses": {
        "question1": "goodbye",
        "question2": "world"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get a `$sum` of all the people who have given the response `hello` to `question1` and all the people who have given the response `world` to `question2`.

For example. I want a response that looks something like this:

```
{ 'question1': 1, 'question2': 2 }
```

My query looks like this, but it isn't working. It's only returning `0` for any given sum when I know that's not the case.

```
db.collection(collection).aggregate([
  { $match : { } },
  { $group: {
     _id: "responses", 
     "question1": { $sum: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$sample.responses.question1", "hello"] }, 1, 0 ] } },
     "question2": { $sum: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$sample.responses.question2", "world"] }, 1, 0 ] } }
    }
  }
])
```

Can anyone help me out?